# Pivot Chart is blank in Excel 2013

Tags: excel

I have a lot of data I'm trying to capture in a pivot chart but every time I generate a chart it's blank, what am I doing wrong?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EZnA.png

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you don't have anything in the values section of the pivot, so there isnt actually anything to plot on the graph.

Comment: Hi sir, is there a way to preserve the axis of the graph despite having no data? (or filter resulting in no data)